# SQL compare from c1.fieldA to c2.fieldB When equal to certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

veh_user table:
[image]

veh_model table:
[image]

I have the user Identifier: `steam:110000104bd6595` corresponding to `veh_user.user`.
I want to select all the field that respect:

1. veh_user.user = steam:110000104bd6595
2. the `result from the 1)`.model = veh_model.id_model WHERE `type = 3`

I don't know if I'm clear here, but I need the result to operate, and I want to know if there is a better solution than made 2 requests

Comment: Use JOIN query to join your two tables.

Comment: Thanks for the negatives votes, but please, tell me what's wrong on this demand.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I tried but I can't succeed, I used INNER JOIN but can't used the result of the first condition...

Comment: Could you paste your query here? I will help you to correct it

Comment: @Izio: You're literally describing the `JOIN` keyword.  What did you try?  What was the result?  What was the expected result?  Why?

Comment: I firstly tried this, but as I said, I can't use the "result" : `SELECT * FROM veh_user, veh_model WHERE veh_user.user=@userId AND veh_model.model =  `

Comment: @Izio: (1) That's not a `JOIN`.  You *claimed* to have used `INNER JOIN`, where is that?  (2) *Why* can't you "use the result"?  What's the *actual problem*?

Comment: Then I used this, but I need the veh_model.type = 3 ... `SELECT * FROM veh_user INNER JOIN weh_model ON veh_user.model = veh_model.id_model WHERE veh_user.user='steam:110000104bd6595'`

Comment: @Izio: So what's stopping you from adding `AND veh_model.type = 3` to your `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from veh_user u
inner join veh_model m
on m.id_model = u.model
where u.user = 'steam:110000104bd6595'
and m.type = 3
```

Comment: This is the very good way but it seems like there is an error here :
` [ERROR] [MySQL] An critical error happens on MySQL for query "SELECT * FROM veh_user u INNER JOIN veh_model m ON m.id_model=u.model WHERE u.user=@id AND m.type=@type {@type=3;@id=steam:110000104bd6595}": An item with the same key has already been added. `

Comment: @Izio: This query isn't *adding* any "key" to anything.  Where specifically are you seeing this error?

Comment: specifically? Uhm... In a mysql async wrapper for LUA : https://github.com/brouznouf/fivem-mysql-async

Comment: Agree with @David, this is a read only operation. Are you running an `update` or `insert` ?

Comment: @Izio: Then you're running into a problem in your use of that library which was never mentioned in the question and has nothing to do with what was asked.  Sounds like an ORM of some kind which is trying to infer a key in a returned result and needs some other consideration for joined tables.  Perhaps you need to more explicitly define the columns being returned instead of selecting all.  Or perhaps you need to use the library in a different way than what you actually asked about.

Comment: Thanks for your time David

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate solution that avoids the use of `join`:

```
select * from veh_user vu
where vu.user = 'steam:110000104bd6595'
      and exists(select 1 from veh_model
                 where type = 3 and model_id = vu.model)
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from some explanation. Why is it better than the answer by @CSPei?

Comment: @divibisan Well, I don't claim it's better. Also, does CSPei provide explanation? I just gave alternate solution which doesn't use `join`. Anyway, the answer is very basic and doesn't require explanation.

Comment: I'm not attacking you and your question; I'm just trying to make it a more useful resource for others.

Comment: @divibisan OK :) I just answered your doubts, didn't mean to "attack" you in any way :)

Comment: No worries! Internet communication is tricky (for me at least) and I hope that I didn't offend you with my first comment.